# Trouble testing Swift in Objective-C test

Tags: objective-c, swift, testing, precompiled

I am testing `myObjCClass` which uses a forward declaration to get a Swift class I'm using, I did this because I was getting "failed to emit precompiled header" if I imported the Bridging Header in the `.h` file. In forward declaration my bridging header import (`-Swift.h`) is in the `.m` file. When I try to test this I am able to test my Swift Class but not the classes that inherit from this. I have tried adding #import `"MyProject-Swift.h"` in my test but I will get the error `file not found`.

```
- Obj-C.h file:

// forward declaration
@class mySwiftClass;

- Obj-C.m file:

//import bridging
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

- Obj-C-Tests.m file:
 
//import that fails
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

How can I fix this? I just want to test the Swift classes I am using in my Objective-C code.

I have already tried making a new bridging header and importing the main target one into the new test target bridging header, that will give me another "failed to emit precompiled header" I have also tried to set the test target bridging header to the main targets bridging header.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the -Swift.h bridging header file is generated automatically into the `DerivedSources` directory, which is not in the header search path of other targets.

Therefore, you need to add it:

- Open the the test target settings
- Navigate to Build settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths
- Add the value `$CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/`*Your-project-name*`.build/DerivedSources`

[image: Header Search Path example]

Now the import (and everything) should work:
[image: Test outcome]